# How to pass a parameter using post method and get response from url and display it in android using gson and volley?

Tags: php, android, json, android-volley, gson

I would like to pass 2 parameters using POST method and get that response from API developed using php. I would like to use GSON and Volley for it.

I have written one method and calling it in onCreate method.This is my method class -

```
private void loadDetailed() {
        //Toast.makeText(DetailedBoatActivity.this, "Called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent i = getIntent();
        Integer boat_id = i.getExtras().getInt("boat_id");
        Integer owner_id = i.getExtras().getInt("owner_id");
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Map<String, Integer> jsonMap = new HashMap<>();
        jsonMap.put("boat_id", boat_id);
        jsonMap.put("owner_id", owner_id);
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonMap);
        Log.d("jsonObject", String.valueOf(jsonObject));
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, DETAILED_BOAT_URL, jsonObject, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    Toast.makeText(DetailedBoatActivity.this, "Try", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);
                    Log.i("array1", String.valueOf(array));

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(DetailedBoatActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });
        Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(jsonObjectRequest);
    }
```

But I am not getting any response from my API. Here is my code -

```
public function boatDetails($id, $owner_id){
            $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT * FROM `boat_details` WHERE id=".$id);
            $stmt->execute();
            $resultSet = $stmt->get_result();
            $boat_details = array();
            while($result = $resultSet->fetch_assoc()){
                $boat_details[] = $result;
            }

            return $boat_details;   
        }
```

I have checked manually. I am getting values in JSON format by using below code -

```
require_once '../includes/dboperations.php';

    $response = array();

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

        //if($_GET['boat_id']){

            $db = new DbOperations();

            $resultSet = $db->boatDetails($_POST['boat_id'], $_POST['owner_id']);

            echo json_encode($resultSet);
        //}
    }
```

Please help me with passing parameter and get back a response to display entities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    String url = URL.LOGIN_URL + "&mail=" + email + "&pass=" + pwd + ""; 
RequestQueue queue;
queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(YOUR_ACTIVITY_NAME.this);
StringRequest req = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {   }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                System.out.println("error ");
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        queue.add(req);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How to get that response?

Comment: public void onResponse(String response) {   } here response is your response as string and please refer https://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/ for more details

Comment: Accept as answer :)